# Cannot upload photo to Indian eVisa application HELP

Tags: visas, india, applications

I am in the process of applying for an Indian eVisa and have reached the point of uploading my photo. I have been this for several hours now and am at my wits end.

I have already found the other thread on this and tried all of the suggested solutions but nothing works. As that is an older thread and is no longer getting responses, I have started this new one. Please help...

I have followed all the instructions - the photo is the same height and width (in pixels) and below the maximum file size. There are no . in the filename except before the extension and the file is the correct format.

When I try to upload, I get an error saying please upload jpg or jpeg image only. I am trying to upload a jpg file. I have tried reducing the dimensions and image quality, the most recent I tried was 351x351px, 37KB (Min is 10KB max is 1MB) and min px is 350x350, the previous thread suggested trying 1px above the minimum..

Still nothing, I get the error message every time. Any suggestions? Is there a specific size I should use? If there is, other than equal dimensions and file format, it isn't stated anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: at one point you have to use a PDF for goodness sake.  watch out for that also!